# SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file

Tags: flash, slideshow

i am fresher to the flash devekopment. i'm using Flash Develop IDE. i am creating a simple slide show. it works fine in FD when running. i'm moving  that swf file ,required image folder and xml file to desktop.now we run that swf file it's working fine. it shows

> SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///C|/Users/king/Desktop/bin/MyHeart.swf cannot access local resource file:///C|/Users/king/Desktop/bin/heart_broke.png. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
>       at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get content()
>       at Function/()[D:\FlashProjects\My Heart\src\Main.as:62]

i am little confused with this issue. is there any way to handle it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Visit the [Flash Player Global Security Settings Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Then:

1. Click <kbd>Always Allow</kbd>
2. Click <kbd>Edit Locations</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Add Location</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Browse For Folder</kbd>
5. Select the location that your SWF will be located at.
6. Click <kbd>Confirm</kbd>

This should solve your issue.

Comment: ok but what if you need to do that from the command line? (on a server)

Comment: @mika What are you talking about?

Comment: I have a swif file running on the backend with the standalone player and get these security errors.

Answer (score 2):

In 22.0.0.209 Flash version:

Open Flash Player Setting Manager
-> Advanced
-> Trusted Location Settings
-> Add (folder or file)

Answer (score 1):

@Marty Answer not works for me now a days.

To access flash players settings, In Windows,  You have to go to the installation path, generally C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FlashPlayerApp.exe
Clikc on Advanced Tab, then the second button (Trust location configuration) and click in add and add your folder where is your swf.

That way, you give permissions on the folder where your swf cannot access the local files

[image]
[image]